# magento static block insert php file

Tags: php, magento, block

i must insert into static block the output of php file.
because i cannot write into block directly a php code, i have edit an external file called disp_med.php

For example:

```
<?php echo 'hello'; ?>
```

From static block i must call disp_med.php. I have inserted (into CMS Static Block):

```
<div id="dispmed"></div>
<script>
var url='http://example.com/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product/disp_med.php';
jQuery('#dispmed').load(url).fadeIn();
</script>
```

But it does not work...

Why?

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can create a phtml file and then call it into your CMS Block.
You can write your code PHP in the phtml.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="your/dir/dispmed.phtml"}}
```

So the file is located at:

```
app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTEMPLATE/template/your/dir/dispmed.phtml
```

This is not a best practice of course but it works...

Comment: Thank's. 
Now file is loaded but an error occour.
"Fatal error: Call to a member function getCategoryIds() on a non-object in /home/lentieit/test/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/catalog/product/disp_medici.phtml on line 2"

this is the code
<?php
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
 foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
  if ($categoryId==6) {
  echo '1';
  }
  if ($categoryId==5) {
  echo '2'i;    
  }
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
  }
?>

Answer (score 0):

`"core/template"` does not have access to `getCategoryIds()` method.

Change the block type to connect your template with the parent block that has those methods:

```
<block type="catalog/category_view"catalog/category_view
{{block type="catalog/category_view"
```

Or...

```
catalog/layer_view
```

Or...

```
catalog/product_list
```

Unfortunately `getCategoryIds()` is a data call which can be replaced by `getData( 'category_ids' )` so it's much harder to find the parent block you're looking for.

If the above block parents don't work for you, find where you copied the code from `<?php $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>` and find the template's parent block in the layout.xml